# How to get each JSON child of an array, postgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have postgreSQL 9.3 and working with json, my field json in DB looks like:

```
{
    "route_json": [
        {
            "someKeys": "someValues",
            "time": 123
        },
        {
            "someKeys": "someValues",
            "time": 123
        }, ... N
    ]
}
```

In my case I need to catch the 'time' element from each element of route_json array and set them in new array. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not pretty:

```
SELECT
  value->'time'
FROM 
  json_array_elements('{"route_json": [{"someKeys": "someValues","time": 123},{"someKeys": "someValues","time": 456}]}'::json->'route_json');
```

Comment: On the contrary, that's gorgeous. Only ugly part is the JSON itself. Here's what it looks like if the JSON is a variable: `SELECT value->'time' FROM json_array_elements(my_json->'route_json');`.